# Accessing an index/value inside a key (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, key, indexof

I've got a dictionary with 18 different keys, each has 3 values inside (`xPower`, `xPP` and `xAccuracy`) each variable holds an int. How would I access one value from a certain key? For example, I want to take out the value of `ScratchPower` (40) for use elsewhere. After searching for over half an hour the most I have found is accessing all the values from a key:

```
print defMoves["Scratch"]
```

Here is my dictionary:

```
defMoves = {
    "Scratch": [ScratchPower, ScratchPP, ScratchAccuracy],
    "Air Slash": [Air_SlashPower, Air_SlashPP, Air_SlashAccuracy],
    "Flare Blitz": [Flare_BlitzPower, Flare_BlitzPP, Flare_BlitzAccuracy],
    "Growl": [GrowlPower, GrowlPP, GrowlAccuracy],
    "Heat Wave": [Heat_WavePower, Heat_WavePP, Heat_WaveAccuracy],
    "Ember": [EmberPower, EmberPP, EmberAccuracy],
    "Shadow Claw": [Shadow_ClawPower, Shadow_ClawPP, Shadow_ClawAccuracy],
    "Smokescreen": [SmokescreenPower, SmokescreenPP, SmokescreenAccuracy],
    "Dragon Claw": [Dragon_ClawPower, Dragon_ClawPP, Dragon_ClawAccuracy],
    "Dragon Rage": [Dragon_RagePower, Dragon_RagePP, Dragon_RageAccuracy],
    "Scary Face": [Scary_FacePower, Scary_FacePP, Scary_FaceAccuracy],
    "Fire Fang": [Fire_FangPower, Fire_FangPP, Fire_FangAccuracy],
    "Flame Burst": [Flame_BurstPower, Flame_BurstPP, Flame_BurstAccuracy],
    "Wing Attack": [Wing_AttackPower, Wing_AttackPP, Wing_AttackAccuracy],
    "Slash": [SlashPower, SlashPP, SlashAccuracy],
    "Flamethrower": [FlamethrowerPower, FlamethrowerPP, FlamethrowerAccuracy],
    "Fire Spin": [Fire_SpinPower, Fire_SpinPP, Fire_SpinAccuracy],
    "Inferno": [InfernoPower, InfernoPP, InfernoAccuracy],
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defMoves["Scratch"]` returns a list so just index like you would any list:

```
defMoves["Scratch"][0]  # first subelement -> ScratchPower
defMoves["Scratch"][1]  # second subelement -> ScratchPP
defMoves["Scratch"][2]  # third subelement -> ScratchAccuracy
......
```

Comment: Thanks greatly appreciated! I tried doing `defMoves["Scratch"[0]]` So now I see where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

defMoves["Scratch"] gets you back the value, which in this case is a list, associated with that key. To get a specific item from that list, you need to use a numeric index. So, for example, to get ScratchPower, you'd use defMoves["Scratch"][0].

That seems hard to keep track of, though, so you may want to use another dictionary inside each of these dictionaries. That'd look like

```
{"Scratch" : {"Power":40... }... }
```